# Highchart : Drawing a 45 degree reference line

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to plot some charts using Highcharts.
I want to show a 45 degree line as a permanent reference line on all the charts.
Highcharts has the option of plot lines but I am unable to find any examples for a 45 degree reference line.

Comment: you can use line chart from (0,0) to (n,n), where n is the max of both x and y axes

Comment: Can you please give the calculation for drawing the line is at 45 degrees always irrespective of the height and width of the chart ?

Comment: I referred the documentation of `plotLines`, but I do did not get any options to place it at 45 degrees. So I think you should refer `renderer` API to draw a `path`. Here is the link: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path

Comment: For reference you can take a look at this static demo which I have made: http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/XvjfL/

Comment: You can also use rotation parameter http://jsfiddle.net/XvjfL/1/